# Font Face: OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

Tags: шрифты

Здравствуйте! Хочу добавить шрифт `Gotham Pro Black` на сайт для заголовков.

В CSS везде прописан `font-weight`. Я правильно понимаю, что тогда нужно добавить только Regular шрифт, т.к. font-weight 900 превратит его в `bold`? Или добавлять сразу bold?

В любом случае, присоединил его через

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Gotham Pro;
  src: url('fonts/GothaProReg.otf');
  }
```

В консоле ошибка:

> OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

Пробовал другие форматы + прописывал `type`

Как можно решить? Спасибо!

Comment: Upd: Проблема, кстати, была связана с доменом. Нужно было прописать полный путь.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> font-family: Gotham Pro;
> ```

```
font-family: 'Gotham Pro';
```